# Verifying an unverified email address?

Tags: php, mysql, architecture

Say a user registers on a site with an email address that needs to be verified first before accepting the user's registration.

The general approach is to send an email to the email address provided. The user then checks his/her inbox and clicks a link that would tell the site that the email address is valid. Usually, the link would have some sort of code embedded in it that tells the site whether it's a legit validation of the email address.

My question is about the code. What's the best way to implement it? Some ideas:

1. A random string is generated when a new address is entered into the site. This random string is stored in the the DB and then emailed to the registrant. The link in the email will contain the random string as part of the URL.
2. The email addressed is hashed. This means nothing needs to be saved in the database because the application will know how to unhash this. (My concern with this approach is if the user later changes his email address to something he previously entered, the hash would be the same. Not sure if this poses some sort of security threat.)
3. Some other approach?

I'm looking for general advice to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number one, the random string, is the safest (and AFAIK, the most common) way to go: It makes it completely impossible to maliciously do things to E-Mail addresses that I haven't received the E-Mail for.

Also, you can remove the random string after successful completion, making it clear that that particular address doesn't need activation any more.

Comment: Pekka, I actually plan to have `verified_email_address` and `unverified_email_address` fields in my database. I suppose now I would also have a `verification_code` field, as well. The reason I think I need 2 fields for email address is so that the user can change his email address later on. During that transition, I would need to record both email addresses, right? And since my verified email addresses need to be unique, I'll need the application layer to check that the unverified email address does not exist in both fields???

Comment: @Stack that sounds sensible. Alternatively, I guess you could have a "verified" flag that gets removed if the user changes their E-Mail address - that might have the same effect. The big guns like Google do it completely differently: They allow you to have a number of E-Mail addresses, all of which you have to activate individually. But that level of complexity may not be always necessary

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie: Second-time verification is troublesome. How do you tell the difference between a) a legitimate user whose old email address no longer works (maybe the domain registration lapsed, or password recovery didn't work), and b) an illegitimate user who's trying to hijack an existing account? If you email a verification link to the old email address, the legitimate user won't get the email. If you email to the new email address, the legitimate user's account gets hijacked. (Security questions are intended to help with this problem.)

Comment: In order to change the user's email address, the user must already be logged in the system. If the user is logged in the system, it is assumed that the user is legit and should be able to change his/her account email address. Sending a email notification to the old email address might at least help prevent potential hijacking?

Answer (score 2):

i'm using 1st approach every time

1. Create a random code
2. Store it at DB
3. Mail it to user with clickable link like activation.php?key=blabla
4. At activation page let user able to enter it manually too
5. At submit compare the keys
6. Activate user
7. If user change mail adress return 1